# How do I open a file from a URL in Laravel 4

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a URL of a pdf or a an image. I want to get that file and store it on my server.

I know laravel has File::get(), but can this open a file from a web url and then do File::put() to a a folder on the server?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

thanks!

Here is what I have:

`$shared_folder = $destinationPath.'/shared'
if(!File::isDirectory($shared_folder)){
    File::makeDirectory($shared_folder,0777,true,true);
    File::get($attachment->link);
    $file_name =$file->getClientOriginalName();
    File::put($shared_folder,$file);
    $new_location = $shared_folder = $destinationPath.'/shared/.'.$file_name;
}`

Comment: You may just have to use PHP's raw [`cURL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know laravel has File::get(), but can this open a file from a web url and then do File::put() to a a folder on the server?

No - this will only access a local resource.

You need to use cURL and access the resource. I suggest using the [Guzzle package](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) which allows for an easy way to use cURL.

Then you could do something like this

```
function getFile($fromUrl, $toFile) {
    $client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
    $response = $client->get($fromUrl);
        ->setResponseBody($toFile)
        ->send();
    return true;
}
```